# chromecast on chrome packaged app

Tags: google-cast, chromecast, google-chrome-app

I would like to add the ability to cast my chrome packaged app to a google chromecast device. 
So far google states that all you have to do is add 
to your page and the API will inject itself. 
For me that doesn't happen. No code is injected.

Am I doing something wrong? 
There doesn't seem to be a demo showing this type of capability.

EDIT:
I just wanted to clarify a bit. All that I would like to do is display my app to a screen. 
I have no media. I simply want to display it exactly as the chrome extension in the chrome browser would.Therefore I would follow the directions for a sender only. The app is packaged so it is running only CSS/JS/HTML5 code. The app is designed to run offline. 
Steps I've taken to cast:
1. I've added the extra bit to the HTML line:

2. I've followed the whitelisting, to the best of my understanding, by adding my "website address" to the chrome extension. So I've added the only two address that should matter. 
127.0.0.1
192.168.1.106

Comment: Are you getting any messages in the console (either window or background)?

Comment: Hi @sowbug Nothing appears in the console that is new. Google says that I should be able to see variables injected into my window variable, but I see nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good chance [Content Security Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/contentSecurityPolicy.html) is blocking the implementation of the cast API being injected. I see that you've filed [Issue 287254: Google cast (chromecast) ability for packaged apps](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287254), and suspect we will need to wait for it to be implemented in a packaged apps compliant way.

Comment: Chrome packaged apps does not have api to connect to chromecast. This is a pending feature in the chromium project. This is the issue crosponding to this feature https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=287254.
It was reported on Sep, 2013 and the issue has been Untriaged, which means there is no ETA and the fix might get delayed another 2 years. If you star the issue it might get some attention from the chromium team.

Comment: Hi @SushantKr ; thanks for the heads up on the bug report, I was the one that filed it.

Answer (score 0):

You must whitelist your device and your Chrome app.  See here for more details:
https://developers.google.com/cast/whitelisting#whitelist-chrome

Comment: Hi @Doug Lamb, since my app is not "online" per se, I only added my local lan and 127.0.0.1 to the list. Still nothing happens. My app runs normally, no API injected.

Comment: @JParrish88 I don't believe it matters. From the [Chrome App Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/cast/chrome_sender): _"The extension checks if the host page is whitelisted for the API. The API will only be injected into pages that match the patterns in the extension manifest or the whitelist in the developer options."_

Comment: @JParrish88 I see now that you edited your question before my last response (sorry I missed that).  It sounds like you're doing it correctly.  I just tested the [example app](https://github.com/googlecast/cast-chrome) on github using 127.0.0.1 and it worked for me. Maybe try that app and make sure it works.

Comment: @JParrish88 you probably realize this but just to make sure since you stated the "app is designed to run offline". You must be online in order for the cast api to be injected.

Comment: It took me a few tries but I finally understand.  I didn't recognize that packaged apps are different from Chrome extension apps.  I suspect @vincent-scheib is correct. Sorry for the noise.